# MacBook 2008 blank install OS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, macbook

So I just got this MacBook 2008 and the hard disk is completely empty. I checked on my Windows computer there is not even a volume on it.

How do I go about installing an OS on it? Any OS.

I am not a Mac user, but I have a linux desktop and a Windows laptop. No Macs however. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: newer macs can pull in the OS off an internet connection IIRC. Not entirely sure if it'll work for this specific model, or if it'll actually work.

Comment: So my optical drive is shotty. I'm going to try the USB route. I'll jus try the free os.